# how to retain values in the following method?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
@interface SignDocumentController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableString *signFaxString;
    NSString * messageId;
    NSMutableData *xmlData;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress2;


    NSString * annotationKey;

    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSString *date;
    NSString *signature;


    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView * image;


@end

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"SignatureInfo"]) {

        signFaxString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init]; 

        firstName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
        lastName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"LastName"];
        date = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
        signature = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Signature"];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"AddAnnotationResult"]) {
        signFaxString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init]; 
    }


}
```

the values for firstName, lastName, date, signature do not stay and I get an error when I try accessing firstName, lastName ETC in a different method:

[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4ec63b0

I have tried using :

```
firstName = [NSString stringWithString attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
```

but that does not work either. I know this is a silly question but I could use some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could also declare the `firstName` and others as property and `retain` . As below

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* firstName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* lastName;    
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* date;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* signature;
```

**And in .m class.**

```
@synthesize firstName,date,lastName,signature;
```

and release them in `dealloc` function.

Use with `self` all your property variable in you class.

```
self.firstName = [NSString stringWithString:attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
```

**EDITED:**

Also consider **@bbum**  comment ..

Comment: Does using self make a difference?

Comment: @jini : using `self` with property variable will implicitly **retain** variables for you without specify `retain` explicitly. It all happen in **setter** function of your property variable.

Comment: The properties should be `copy`, not `retain`.  Otherwise correct.

Comment: @jhaliya: I am still getting : NSString may not respond to stringWithString warning.

Comment: self.firstName = [NSString stringWithString: attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
  
  
  
  
  self.lastName = [NSString stringWithString:attributeDict objectForKey:@"LastName"];
  self.date = [NSString stringWithString: attributeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
  self.signature = [NSString stringWithString: attributeDict objectForKey:@"Signature"];

Comment: Break below statement
`self.firstName = [NSString stringWithString:attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];`
Into two line

`NSString* string  = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
if(string)
{
   self.firstName =   [NSString stringWithString:string ];
}`

Comment: OK that worked find and I will mark your answer correct. However I am dying to know why we had to break it up in two lines?

Comment: @jini `self.firstName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"];` suffices. `+[NSString stringWithString:]` is unnecessary and there is no need for two statements there.

Comment: @jini Also, see bbum’s comment about the properties being `copy` instead of `retain`.

Comment: Thanks Bavarious. I already knew about the copy. I appreciate your help and feedback on this question.

Answer (score 2):

To retain it, just send a `retain` message to the object.

```
firstName = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"FirstName"] retain];
```

`release` it later.